# What kind of data structure will be best for storing a key-value pair where the value will be a String for some key and a List<String> for some keys?

Tags: data-structures, language-agnostic

For example, key 1 will have values  "A","B","C" but key 2 will have value "D". If I use

```
Map<String, List<String>>
```

I need to populate the `List<String>` even when I have only single String value.
What data structure should be used in this case?

Comment: That seems reasonable to me. I think it's a pretty common hashtable implementation - to use a linked list in each bucket to deal with collisions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Map<String,List<String>>` would be the standard way to do it (using a size-1 list when there is only a single item).

You could also have something like `Map<String, Object>` (which should work in either Java or presumably C#, to name two), where the value is either `List<String>` or `String`, but this would be fairly bad practice, as there are readability issue (you don't know what `Object` represents right off the bat from seeing the type), casting happens during runtime, which isn't ideal, among other things.

It does however depend what type of queries you plan to run. `Map<String,Set<String>>` might be a good idea if you plan of doing existence checks in the `List` and it can be large. `Set<StringPair>` (where `StringPair` is a class with 2 `String` members) is another consideration if there are plenty of keys with only 1 mapped value. There are plenty of solutions which would be more appropriate under various circumstances - it basically comes down to looking at the type of queries you want to perform and picking an appropriate structure according to that.